# Django uploaded file permissions

Tags: django

How to add permissions to uploaded file?

E.g

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')
    owner = models.ForeigKey(AuthUser)
```

And each logged user can add te images. E.g. User1 added image a.jpg. And can access it by adresserver.com/cars/a.jpg but anyone can access it too. How add permissions to only owner can see the image?

Comment: I think no need to add permission as the loged user records saves with uploading image.So that you can filter your or loged user images with their current user object from request (request.user).

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the view that serves the image to only show the image if the logged in user is the owner:

`photo_to_show = get_object_or_404(Car, owner=request.user, photo=photo)`